# What will be the orbit of the group action $G \times X \to X$ by $(g,H)=ghg^{-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

> What will be the orbit of the group action $G \times X \to X$ by $(g,H)=ghg^{-1}$ where $G$ is any group and $X$ is the set of all the subgroups of $G$?

If $H$ is normal then the orbit of $H$ will be $\{H\}$.
But if $H$ is not normal then what will be the orbit of $H$?
In case of $S_3$ I saw that the orbit of any subgroup of order $2$ is all the subgroups of order $2$. Is it true in general?

Comment: The fact that $S_3$ acts transitively on the set of its order two subgroups is just an instant of the Sylow theorems.

Comment: These are called the *conjugate* subgroups. A normal subgroup is one with no conjugate subgroups (except itself). We refer to $gHg^{-1}$ as the $g$-conjugate of $H$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right about $S_3$, but it is not true in general. Consider, for instance $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and take $H=\left\{(\operatorname{id},0),\bigl((1\ \ 2),0\bigr)\right\}$. Then $\{(\operatorname{id},0),(\operatorname{id},1)\}$ doesn't belong to the orbit of $H$, in spite of the fact that it is a subgroup with two elements.

In general, the orbit of $H$ will be a set of subgroups of $H$ all of which have the same order as $H$, but it doesn't have to be the set of *all* such subgroups.